# Append request header post spring security authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security, microservices, netflix-zuul

We would like to add header to our request post spring security authentication has happened.

However, headers are not getting appended. 
We were able to do it through a Zuul filter but not with spring security filter.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    httpServletRequestWrapper = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(request) {
        @Override
        public String getHeader(String name) {
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(ENV - HEADER)) {

                return active;
            } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(USERID)) {

                return (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
            } else {
                return super.getHeader(name);
            }
        }
    };

    filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequestWrapper, servletResponse);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the filter to add Header to request after `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` in your security config file.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.exceptionHandling().and().anonymous().and().servletApi().and().headers().and().authorizeRequests()

    // Your existing security configurations

    // Assuming UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter is the filter 
    .addFilterAfter(new AddHeaderFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` is the enbuild spring filter which runs for spring security authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Add your yml or property file configuration to

```
zuul:
  sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie
  add-proxy-headers: true
```

then zuul allow header to go other end points.